# Is it possible to have a subordinate clause inside a relative clause?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, subordinate-clause, relative-clause

Can one have a subordinate clause inside a relative clause?

What I want to write in English is this:

> The economic crisis which started in 2007 resulted in mergers and state intervention,  which meant the company became 50% state owned.

My first attempt was this:

> Die Wirtschaftskrise, die von 2007 fing an, führte zu Fusionen und staatlicher Eingriff, der bedeutete, dass die Geschäft 50% Staatsbesitz wurde.

However, in the second relative clause the finite verb ought to go to the end of the clause, which would result in:

> Die Wirtschaftskrise, die von 2007 fing an, führte zu Fusionen und staatlicher Eingriff, der, dass die Geschäft 50% Staatsbesitz wurde, bedeutete.

That looks wrong to me with my basic command of German.

Is such a construction correct?  Is it allowed, but frowned upon by right thinking people? Is there a better way of expressing this phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This construction is not correct. In a relative clause the verb is at the end, but not if the relative clause contains a subordinate clause that depends on the verb.

Your first attempt, with a few other mistakes corrected:

> Die Wirtschaftskrise, die 2007 anfing, führte zu Fusionen und staatlichen Eingriffen, die bedeuteten, dass die Firma zu 50% Staatsbesitz wurde.

Comment: This is correct, however I would suggest to split the sentence into two parts, why not write:
>`Die Wirtschaftskrise, die 2007 anfing, führte zu Fusionen und staatlichen Eingriffen; diese bedeuteten, dass die Firma zu 50% Staatsbesitz wurde.`

Comment: @0x6d64 I think you're right.  Now I reread it, even the original English version is not written very well and should be split.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull the adverbial stuff before the subject

> Die **2007 eingetretene** Wirtschaftskrise führte zu Fusionen und staatlichen Eingriffen, die bedeuteten, dass das Unternehmen zu 50% in Staatsbesitz überging.

It is also possible to substitute *bedeuten*

> Die 2007 eingetretene Wirtschaftskrise führte zu Fusionen und staatlichen Eingriffen **in Folge derer** das Unternehmen zu 50% in Staatsbesitz überging.
>
> Die 2007 eingetretene Wirtschaftskrise führte zu Fusionen und staatlichen Eingriffen, **wobei**  das Unternehmen zu 50% verstaatlicht wurde.